# Apache Camel - When can a file be renamed?

Tags: apache-camel

I found a sample code something like this:

```
from("file:/opt/input").multicast().parallelprocessing().to("direct:process-with-bindy","direct:move-to-out").end();
```

`from("direct:move-to-out").setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple(rename using current time)).
to("file:/opt/done").end();`

Does it mean that the same file will be renamed during the bindy processing and that the renaming will not be affected the bindy route?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means that the file will be sent to bindy and move-to-out at the same time, essentially splitting the execution into 2 threads, they will happen at the same time and the file will not be renamed in the bindy processing (unless it does it as part of the route from "process-with-bindy").

[Sending the same message to multiple endpoints](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-send-the-same-message-to-multiple-endpoints.html) explains how this is different from sending it to one endpoint and then using the result of the first as the input of the second.

Edit:
When camel picks up a file it creates an exchange from it, it's the exchange that is being manipulated and processed by bindy. The bindy processing thread doesn't know that the exchange has been copied and is being written out as a new file elsewhere so there won't be a conflict.

It's easy to test this:

```
public class FileSplitTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:target/todo")
                        .multicast()
                        .parallelProcessing()
                        .to("direct:process", "direct:file-out").end();

                from("direct:process")
                        .delayer(500)
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                assertTrue("Hello World".equals(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)));
                            }
                        })
                        .to("file:target/done");

                from("direct:file-out")
                        .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("new name"))
                        .to("file:target/done");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String isMockEndpoints() {
        return "file:target/done";
    }

    @Test
    public void testFileSplit() throws InterruptedException {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("file:target/todo", "Hello world", Exchange.FILE_NAME, "todo.txt");

        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:file:target/done");
        mockEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(2);

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But if process-with-bindy is processing the file, will "move-to-out" break the processing by renaming the same file in parallel?